# Passed variable not working on PDO

Tags: php, variables, pdo

I have a passed variable that should be loaded on a PHP-PDO query, but I get this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Here is my code:

```
$color = $_GET['color'];    
$items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = :colorbase1");
$items = bindValue(':colorbase1', $color);
```

Any syggestions? thanks!

Comment: How and where do you create $con ?

Comment: The syntax of the bind is correct, either you $_GET is empty or you aren't making the connection properly.

Comment: Which part of the error message is it that you do not understand specifically?

Comment: @Fluffeh I find it more likely that `$con` isn't an object, as that's what the error says.

Comment: $con is included in the file separately. And it should work since this error happens in an IF sentence. However, when getting into the ELSE another query is run `$items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr ORDER BY date DESC");` and it works perfectly

Comment: AND the $_GET is fine since I am echoing the value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare $con in your script before the $con->prepare

```
$con =  new PDO($dns, $user, $pass);
```

Comment: That is more a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$color = $_GET['color'];    
$items = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = :colorbase1");
$items->bindValue(':colorbase1', $color);
$items->execute();
```

:D have fun

Comment: Thanks, but I was executing further down
`$items ->execute();
while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`

Comment: Did this fixed ur problem? if no, can you give post the piece of the code to pastebin and give the link to? ))